# Blank page when accessing ../wp-admin and the contents page

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I get a blank white page when accessing wp-admin and the contents page.
I'm using openshift hosting and wordpress.

Here's the error log:

> [Sat Apr 11 11:11:12 2015] [error] [client 127.4.198.1] PHP Fatal
>   error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'
>   (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/data/plugins/papercut/inc/phpQuery/:/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/data/plugins/papercut/inc/phpQuery/plugins/')
>   in
>   /var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/data/plugins/extrawatch-pro/extrawatch.php
>   on line 57

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you check to see that the file exists? `ls -lah filename`.  Also can you post the permissions on the file as well `ls -lah filaneme`

Comment: sorry, can you explain it in more detail. because I am not familiar with web programming languages

Comment: I am asking if you can check the file permissions on the server where your site is running.

Comment: Can you ssh into the machine or get shell access?

Comment: ?  Your last post doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry. my english is bad. because i use translator.

Comment: I've ssh into the machine using FileZilla

Comment: It is saying it can't find `/var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`.  Additionally its saying its looking outside of wordpress and cant find it.  Run `ls -lah /var/lib/openshift/5528a392fcf933f54d000067/app-root/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`